# Distributed cache with Pig and Python

Tags: apache-pig, distributed-cache

I know there are a lot of resources for using distributed cache in Pig scripts with Java-udfs. But I haven't found anything that would explain the same with python udfs.
Also, I have not found any detailed explanation of distributed cache usage while writing pig scripts.

I am not asking for any question. But I want to have a place where people like me can get their first pig + python + distributed cache example working.  I am sorry if I am unknowingly asking the wrong question. But I will be very thankful for the help.

Thanks,
r0ger22

Comment: Pig Streaming Functions - is what you should search for. refer http://arnon.me/2013/03/herding-apache-pig-pig-perl-python/ and https://wiki.apache.org/pig/PigStreamingFunctionalSpec

Comment: Pig Streaming Functions is a way of launching pig josb like hadoop Streaming. Ship feature in pig will ship your python code to all nodes (like distributed cache)

Comment: @ramisetty.vijay  Ok. I got that.  What I am looking for is (and perhaps I should have mentioned that in the question specifically; apologies for that):

I have a config file, which I must load in memory. Right now, what i am doing is - I have kept this file on my hdfs cluster. Then, LOAD it in my PIG Job and then join it whenever needed.  But I would ideally want to not keep this on hdfs but SHIP it to all nodes (just like python code is shipped).
I am having trouble with shipping the config files, basically.